# How to sort a Document Library exported to Access 2013 by filename

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, migration, document-migration

I have a SharePoint 2013 list that I have linked to MS Access. When I try to sort the table by the file name, the option to sort A ---> Z is grayed out. What is the limitation that I am running into? How may I get around it?

**Big picture:** I am working to migrate a Document Library from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013. I have created a Document library in 2013 to mirror the Library in 2007. I have moved the files between the servers (4,397 of them). Now I wish to move the associated column data from 2007 to 2013. I had hoped to simply copy and paste in datasheet view (2007), but the Quick Edit view (2013) does not allow me to view the whole library at once. The work around was to link the 2013 Document Library to Access and copy and paste from the 2007 Data View to the 2013 Access linked table. I cannot sort the Access table to bring it into alignment with my 2007 Document Library in Data Sheet view.

Comment: Seems that the Advanced menu under Filter on the Home tab gets me most of the way there for the sort. The sort does not stick and the columns rearrange. But as the entire application crashes when I try to manipulate any of the data, I think the problem is bigger than this.

Comment: I relinked the SharePoint Document Library to a brand new database and it seems to function fully this time.

Comment: The essence of this question has been reduced to a method by which to short a column that contains hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sorting this table based upon the Name column as drawn from SharePoint 2013 Document Library is that the Names are hyperlinks.

To sort columns that are hyperlinks, one must use the Advanced drop down from the filter menu on the Home tab of the Ribbon.

Here you can set your sort column in a design screen much like that from which you assemble a query.

Press Toggle Filter to enact your filter after it is set.

The column order can be rearranged here as well.